# EF Code First Mysql to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an MVC 5 application that I first configured to use Mysql but now would like it to use SQL Server.

My app uses code first and migrations in order to generate the database.

After I changed all the required configuration I tried to run a Update-Database from the Package management console but I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not
>   valid. Errors:  (0,0) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'.
>   Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section
>   of the application config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

This error appears after the database is created. It also appears when I run the application since it checks at that moment if there is any migration to do.

Somehow it still tries to use MySQL even though all providers point to SQL Server.

Any help would be more than welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Obviously not all of the providers point to SQLServer

Comment: Very obvious indeed, so much that I tried to check where could that be and couldn't find. Even when I do a full text search on all solution files I cannot find a trace of the word: "Mysql"

Here is my only config file: http://pastebin.com/FVf31aJ9

If you find where the wrong provider is set please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the below mentioned steps to overcome above issue.

**Step 1 :** Use `NuGet package` to `remove` and `install` the relevant packages.This is very important.

If it's not working after the above step then you have to follow the below mentioned steps.

**Step 1 :** Get a backup of your `project` and `SQL db` and keep it in a safe place.

**Step 2 :** After that you have to `delete` all your `data migration scripts` on your app.

**Step 3 :** Delete the `SQL db` also.

**Step 4 :** Recreate all your `Migration scripts again` and after that run those against the `SQL server`.

**Note :** You need to do above steps b'cos it seems `EF` keep the `provider details` on the `db migration scripts`.

Comment: I am gonna try this and come back to you. I didn't try yet to rebuild the migrations.

Comment: I did this and it works fine. Thanks a ton for that!

That being said, I am annoyed by the fact I loose the history of migrations, because of course when I regenerate the migrations it only creates a single one with the current state of the database, while on the mysql side I had 3 different migrations classes.

I tried to compare both the new single migration and the other three mysql migration classes and the only change that is probably causing the issue is the has stored in the resx file in the target field. I guess there is the reference to the MySql provider.

Is there a way ...

Comment: ... to regenerate just the target field while keeping the old migration classes?

Comment: Glad to see that above solution works :) Hope you'll `accept the solution` with `Up vote` :D `to regenerate just the target field while keeping the old migration classes` - Actually that way it won't work.you can try that on separate project.I'm pretty much sure where it won't work.

Comment: I had to wonder around on how to mark it as the right answer but I figured it out (should ask questions more often :D)

I am trying several things but indeed it seems to be impossible to recover those migrations, it is a pity. In this project it doesn't matter much since it is not in production yet but this could become annoying otherwise

Comment: yes,true.But it is very rare to see the changes of `database provider` after the `production` no ? Here you can see how to do basic operations on `SOF`.just scroll it to see all :D http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thank you for the link, might come handy.

I might have found a solution though. The hash stored in the resource file is actually a base64 gziped xml file. And indeed in that file the Mysql provider is mentioned. I will try to change the xml file and recompose the base 64 string. Then I will replace it in the resource file and check if it works. If so I will update this with a link to some utility to do this that I will drop on github