# Migrate ASP.NET MVC from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework. After I finished, the IT told me that they cannot use SQL Server localdb on their server, so I need to transfer to an Oracle database. The problem is, I have no idea how to accomplish this.

What I managed to far: I found out I need to use Oracle Entity Framework and somehow managed to add `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` (the internet is pretty restricted here and I could not use NuGet). I also modified the connection string and provider. The problem is, an exception occurs:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file.

Web.config:

```
<add name="DBCS" 
     connectionString="DATA SOURCE=source;PASSWORD=pass;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user" 
     providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
 ...
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
            type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleConnectionFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                  type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Context and how I use it:

```
 public class InventoryContext : DbContext
 {
    public InventoryContext() : base("DBCS")
    { }
 ...
 }

 InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext();
 db.Items.ToList() //use the rows
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: you have to use `nugget` to `remove` and `add` necessary `components`. other wise very difficult to configure it.

Comment: unfortunately any attempt to use nuget results in this error Install-Package : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

Comment: that is may be restrictions of your internet.how can we help you ?

Comment: @Sampath thank you for your support. Is the usage of the context correct also for Oracle? Or should I modify the provider / anything else in the web.config file? The exception suggests that I should change the provider, but this is the one I found here [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityConfig.htm#ODPNT8266)

Comment: the thing here is all devs are doing it using `nugget`.we can support it if you'll have any issues after the `nugget` update.these days no one is doing it manually. I have sorted out an issue which it came after the nugget update.you can see that here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605532/ef-code-first-mysql-to-sql-server/39606324#39606324

Comment: @Sampath It's called *NuGet*, not *nugget*. And I can assure you there are still lots of companies out there where NuGet is disallowed by policy.

Comment: Thanks @Stijn :) I'll use it correctly next time :)

Comment: I'll try to install the packages with NuGet from home and I'll provide updates (hopefully tomorrow)