# Entity Framework keeps trying to connect to old ADO.NET provider eventhough it has been changed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I changed a MySQL project's DB connection to target SQL Server from MySQL. However, when trying to run `Update-Database -StartProjectName ProjectName` targeting a database in SQL Server, I receive the following error

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (0,0) : error 0152: No Entity
>   Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the
>   'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

So I tried to ensure that my project was free of MySQL

1. Use ctrl+F and search for all MySQL keyword : Found none.
2. Uninstall MySQL packages via NuGET package manager

Why does Entity Framework keep asking me for MySQL provider when I have clearly indicated that it should use the default MS SQL provider in the config file?

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVER123;Database=DB123;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

---

This is my DbContext file:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProjectName.MSSQL
{
    public class ProjectNameContext:DbContext
    {
        public ProjectNameContext()
            : base("Connection")
        {

        }

        public static ProjectNameContext Create()
        {
            return new ProjectNameContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Code First Migrations? Try delete all previous migration codes in Migrations directory, since EF may retain previous DB information inside previous migration scripts. Then recreate those scripts with SQL Server DB, as given in similar issue there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605532/ef-code-first-mysql-to-sql-server.

Comment: You shouldn't have to delete migrations for this to work. Try specifying the connection string explicitly when you run the migration: `Update-Database -ConnectionString "XXX" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" -StartupProject ProjectName`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I reinstalled Entity Framework and it seems to work properly now. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson it still shows the same error. Seems like EF is caching the connection provider. Is there any way to clear it? The current solution is reinstalling EF but this is really just a workaround... Ideally, I should be able to switch the provider with just applying some changes in config...

Comment: @Mark I agree, reinstalling EF is not an ideal solution. The only difference I can see in your configuration compared to what I normally use is that you are defining a default connection factory (this is optional, try removing it). Is your context's constructor explicitly specifying a connection string? If not, it first looks for one named 'FooContext' (or whatever the name of your context class is), failing that it asks the default connection factory to provide a connection, finally it will try the 'DefaultConnection' connection string.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson maybe the issue is in my dbcontext... I have updated the question with my dbcontext.

Comment: That looks pretty standard. The other things to check are the DbMigrationsConfiguration (the last file in the migrations directory), and the DbConfiguration (if you have one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me was [I created my own `DbConfiguration` class and referenced it using the codeConfigurationType property in `App.config`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680699%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

My custom `Dbconfiguration` class

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

namespace ProjectName.MSSQL
{
    public class MSSQLDbConfiguration:DbConfiguration
    {
        public MSSQLDbConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
            this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));
        }
    }
}
```

My App.config

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="ProjectName.MSSQL.MSSQLDbConfiguration, ProjectName.MSSQL">
...
any stuff...
...
</entityFramework>
```